# Namespace is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a javaScript plug-in and I define a namespace in my plugin; but, the web page cannot find it.  Please be as explicit as you be with your answer; as I learn better examining code, watching a video somebody doing **live coding and testing**.

Here is my HTML:

```
    ...  
   <article class="slider_cnt">
        <div class="slider">
          <img src="img/slide1.jpg" />
          <img src="img/slide2.jpg" />
          <img src="img/slide3.jpg" />
        </div>
    </article>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/elegant2_slider.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            elegantNamespace.initialize($('.slider'),'img');  // options setup
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

and my javaScript:

```
(function ($) {
    this.elegantNamespace = this.elegantNamespace || {};
    var ns = this.elegantNamespace;

    // settings
    var $slider; // class or id of carousel slider
    var $slide; // could also use 'img' if you're not using a li
    var $transition_time = 1000; // 1 second
    var $time_between_slides = 2300; // 2.3 seconds
    var $interval;

    ns.initialize = function(fram, slide){  // options setup
        $slider = fram;
        $slide = slide;
        startloop();
    }

    slides = function() {
        return $slider.find($slide);
    }

    slides().fadeOut();

    // set active classes
    slides().first().addClass('active');
    slides().first().fadeIn($transition_time);

    // auto scroll 
    startloop = function () {
        $interval = setInterval(

        function () {
            var $i = $slider.find($slide + '.active').index();

            slides().eq($i).removeClass('active');
            slides().eq($i).fadeOut($transition_time);

            if (slides().length == $i + 1) $i = -1; // loop to start
            slides().eq($i + 1).addClass('active');
            slides().eq($i + 1).fadeIn($transition_time+ 2000);
        }, $transition_time + $time_between_slides);
    }
    pauseLoop = function() {
        window.clearInterval($interval);
    }

    $slider.hover(

    function () {
        pauseLoop(); // pause the loop
    },

    function () {
        startloop(); //scroll()
    });
})();
```

Comment: As a note: While it is up to you how you name your variables, it is common with jQuery to only prefix those variables that are jQuery result set with `$`. Beside that you should not use `this` in a function that is not called in context of another object.

Comment: @charlietfl I thought so too, but I don't see that the OP uses `$` in the function.

Answer (score 1):

The browser recognizes your namespace fine. Your program is bugged.
You created variables **$slider** and **$slide**.
You use the **initialize** function to give those variables values:

```
ns.initialize = function(fram, slide){  // options setup
    $slider = fram;
    $slide = slide;
    startloop();
}
```

Here you have a function that uses those variables:

```
 slides = function() {
    return $slider.find($slide);
}
```

In order for this function to work the variables must be initialized. Meaning that you have to call the **initialize** function before you call the **slider** function.

And this is where your problem is. By calling the **slider** function you are trying to use **$slider** which is not yet initialized. As a result your script breaks:

```
slides().fadeOut();
slides().first().addClass('active');
slides().first().fadeIn($transition_time);
```

At the end of your script you are also trying to use **$slider**:

```
$slider.hover(

function () {
    pauseLoop(); // pause the loop
},

function () {
    startloop(); //scroll()
});
```

To fix this move that code into the **initialize** function. That way it should work. Like this:

```
ns.initialize = function(fram, slide){

    $slider = fram;
    $slide = slide;

    slides().fadeOut();
    slides().first().addClass('active');
    slides().first().fadeIn($transition_time);

    $slider.hover(

    function () {
        pauseLoop();
    },

    function () {
        startloop();
    });

    startloop();

}
```

Comment: I made the edits you suguested and it is not working as surpose to be.  I made a [JSFidde](http://jsfiddle.net/ospena/r6Lomf1t/4/). I am going to put my Github repo; so you can contibute some code to it.  [os-pena](https://github.com/os-pena/Elegant-jQuery-Carousel-Slider)
Thanks, @acehko